R - Optimizing Likelihood Functions for Large Datasets
I'm working on an optimization process using the optim function to maximize a likelihood function with a large dataset. The likelihood function is built using parallel programming (parSapply), and it computes relatively quickly for an individual (less than 20 seconds per subject - the likelihood should be calculated separately within each subject). However, the optimization process is taking an extremely long time due to the large number of subjects (70,000) and observations (3,000,000 from these 70,000 subjects) in the dataset and non-parallel process of the optimization.
Do you have any tips to help speed up the optimization process? Many thanks in advance.
function_lik_par <- function(p){

    loglik <- 0
    subject <- unique(data$id)
    beta0 <- p[1:3]; beta1 <-p[4:5] # intercept - exponential dist/ covariate - time (Gompertz)
    xi <- p[6:7] # misclassification
    data_split <- split(data, data$id)

     L_i <- parSapply(cl, 1:length(subject),       
       function(i) function_par(data_split,i,beta0, beta1,xi))

     sum(L_i)
}

max = optim(par=p0, fn = function_lik_par, 
         method =c("BFGS"), 
         control = list(maxit=3000, fnscale = 100000), hessian = TRUE)


A minimum reproducible example would be very helpful. It should include some data (even a small amount of nominal data). Someone should be able to copy/paste your code and it should run. Also, function_par is not defined.

Consider a two-step strategy: first, take a sample of the subjects (maybe 1,000) and run the optimization (if the 3M observations are per subject, I would also sample the observations). Use the results from the first optimization run as the starting point for a second optimization run that includes all the data.

It looks like you should be able to compute subject and data_split outside of the objective function (i.e. you don't need to do those computations every time you call the objective function). The crux will probably be in whatever's inside function_par (which you haven't shown us ...)
